# I want to echo wordpress post year and i want to link it to year archive

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to echo the year to wordpress posts and link it to exact year archive.
I used this code but  it sends me to localhost/?m=year  it must send me to www.mydomain.com/?m=year
This is the code i used for the link

`href="get_year_link($year);"` <- doesn't work for me

And this is the code i used to echo the post year

`the_time('Y');`  <- this works fine

I don't  know what's wrong with that, the first code inside href sends me to localhost.com/?m=year link instead of sending me to www.mydomain.com/?m=year

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Is your [Site URL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL) set properly?

Comment: Yes it is set properly but thanks for trying to help me. i figured how to do it . different way :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `get_the_time('Y')` function instead of `get_year_link($year)`

Check here for other [time format options](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_time)

Answer (score 0):

### ***Thank you all***

That wasn't what i wanted :) but there is a good news that i figured by myself how to make that.

This was the code needed on single.php : **`$archive_year = get_the_time('Y');`**

This was the code inside the **href="`echo get_year_link( $archive_year );` "**

and this was for echo the year at the post :**`echo get_the_time('Y')`**

But anyway was your help that made me discover this :) ***thank you all*.**

### ***Reg. eXpO***